# AngularJs: select binding and http request

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-select2

I'm a beginner with angular js and I have a problem with http request and binding select.

I have a select menu in a form which is filled like this:

```
$http.get("test").success(function (result) {
        result.forEach(function (e) {
            services.push(e)
        });
});
```

I use the service variable in html like this (I use select2 for select menu):

```
<select id="service" ng-model="requestCtrl.service" multiple ui-select2 data-placeholder="Services sans cache ..." class="default-select" >
   <option ng-repeat="service in requestCtrl.services" value="{{service}}" >{{service}}</option>
</select>
```

All work fine for now.

I save the service variable in localStorage and I restore it in the page loading.

But, in this step, I have a problem.
The variable is well loaded from localStorage but it doesn't appear in the select, it's empty.
If I don't load select options from http service, all work fine.
So I think I have a problem with the select menu loading.

What is wrong in my code ?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd better use ng-options. ng-repeat on <option> tag does not play well in IE. try IE out to see the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your **controller**...

Declare "services" var as part of the `$scope`. Like this:

```
$scope.services = [];
```

In your **HTML**

```
<option ng-repeat="service in services" ....
```

To simplify the answer in angular changes affect the UI when "vars" are associated with the `scope`. I couldn't find that association in your `$http.get` and later `services.push(e)`. This is what I would expect to see:

```
$http.get("test").success(function (result) {
        result.forEach(function (e) {
            $scope.services.push(e);
        });
});
```

On a side note I wonder if your result.forEach could be improved by using `concat` function instead:

```
$scope.services = $scope.services.concat(result);
```

Leaving your code like this:

```
$http.get("test").success(function (result) {
   $scope.services = $scope.services.concat(result);
});
```

Comment: I don't specify I use "controller as" syntax so I access to my variable through my controller like this : ng-repeat="service in requestCtrl.services". In my controller, I do this.services = services (hence the forEach to avoid to lost the reference on service variable)